# Rename the file within each folder regardless of extension

Tags: python, path, operating-system, filenames

So I have folders with different date, I was trying add the date of each folder to the image inside the folder.
My code looks like this:

```
import os, sys
path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
folder=[folder for folder in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(folder)]
print(folder)
for n in range(len(folder)):
    for filename in os.listdir(path+"/"+folder[n]):
        os.rename(filename, filename+folder[n])
```

but it give filename like this:
'IMG_6569 copy.png' -> 'IMG_6569 copy.png10May'.
How can I add the date before the file extension? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You just need to split on the extension and add it after the updated bit like so

```
import os, sys
path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
folder=[folder for folder in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(folder)]
print(folder)
n=0
for n in range(len(folder)):
    for filename in os.listdir(path+"/"+folder[n]):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        os.rename(filename, name + folder[n] + extension)
```